# Error with accents to Run Transformation Kettle Pentaho

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a problem with accents using pentaho data integration to migrate data from sql server to postgresql but just in some cases increases a one symbol.
The data type in Sql Server is type Varchar(MAX) and PostgreSQL is type Text
For Example:

```
Sql Server: CARREOCERÃA
PostgreSQL: CARREOCERÃ?A
```

Version Pentaho: 7.1.0.0-12

Comment: Can you check if it is the encoding : what does say the preview on the SQL-Server input ?

Comment: If you supply minimal DB scripts (create, insert) and a transformation, I'll have a look at my side.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the charset when you define the connection: on the left hand panel click on Option.

These are database properties. For postgres, put `charset` in the `Parameter` column and choose the appropriate `value` from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/multibyte.html).
For SQL-Server, I couldn't find the doc.

For SQL-Server, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969981/unicode-supported-jdbc-connection-with-sqlserver-using-data-source-name) you could set useUnicode=true characterEncoding=UTF-8.